# Sync dropbox and skydrive folders in a dual boot Win7 - Win8

Tags: sync, multi-boot, dropbox, onedrive

My laptop has a dual boot between Windows 7 and Windows 8 Consumer Preview.

On Windows 7, I use both Dropbox and Skydrive desktop apps to sync my files. Let's say the location on the hard drive is D:/Dropbox and D:Skydrive.

I want to install both apps on Windows 8 as well, but I want to use the same folders in order to preserve some hard disk space while keeping my always in sync, whether I boot on Win 7 or Win 8.

I wonder how can I do this without any confilcts between the two Windows installations using the same folder.

Comment: I don't see any problem using the same locations for Dropbox and Skydrive, they are just folders for Windows, nothing special. You may get a problem if you have assigned NTFS permissions to your user or a custom group.

Comment: Did it work?  I have exactly the same scenario and would like to get some feedback before I try it

Comment: @PeterHahndorf no longer true in Windows 10: OneDrive (ex-Skydrive) folders use custom NTFS reparse points.